# How do I move an HTML div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my div containing text to move 10px to the right everytime upon click.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='color-div' style='clear:both; position:relative; left:0;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

And the script:

```
document.getElementById('color-div').style.right='10px';
```

My event is already defined and everything else is working as it should.

Comment: you're likely better off toggling a `class`, whose definition moves the `div` to the proper location.

Comment: I don't see any click handler code.

Comment: `right='10px';` just sets the value of `right` to `10px`. You want to **increase** its *current value* by `10`.

Comment: You're not *moving* it by 10px, you are *setting* it to 10px. You have to get the current position and *add* 10 to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To move the div to the right, you should add to left, not right
2. You need to add a clickhandler to your div.
3. You are setting the style to a fixed value, to increasing it.

Add

```
onclick="moveRight()"
```

to your div, and change your javascript to this:

```
var moveRight = function(){
    var current_offset = parseInt(document.getElementById('color-div').style.left);
    document.getElementById('color-div').style.left = current_offset + 10 + "px";
}
```

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3v4oc2p/)

Answer (score -1):

you might like to use this little javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function example_animate(px) {
    $('#example').animate({
        'marginLeft' : px
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="example_animate('+=50px')" />
```

and instead of moving it on button click, call this function on div click event.

Comment: javascript is tagged not jquery

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery you can achieve this with : **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/73evwzw4/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="click-me"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.click-me {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;    
    position:absolute;
}
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click-me').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var currentLeft = $this.offset().left;
        $this.css("left", currentLeft + 10);      
    });
});
```

Comment: javascript is tagged not jquery